# Convert CSV from an api to a dataframe format in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to python, I have extracted some reviews from a website and I used the api  of the webscrapping tool to import my data in python and the format is in csv. I want to convert this csv to a dataframe in python. Can someone guide me on how to perform this please.

Below is the code for importing the api extraction in csv format.

```
import requests

params = {
  "api_key": "abc",
  "format": "csv"
}
r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs/ttx8PT-EL6Rf/data', params=params)
print(r.text)
```

My output for the above codes are as follows:

```
"selection1_name","selection1_url","selection1_CommentID_name","selection1_CommentID_Date","selection1_CommentID_comment"
"A","https://www..html","137","February 02, 2020","I enjoy the daily package from the start with the welcoming up to the end.
I recommend this hotel."
"A","https://www.e a lot. Relaxing moments with birds chirping, different swings to chill. Overall, I shall visit again. Thanks Azuri & Marideal."
"A","https://www.html","17","June 12, 2019","Had an amazing stay for 2 nights.
The cleanliness of the room is faultless"
"B","https://www.html","133","April 16, 2019","Had a good time. Food is good."
```

etc...
Can you please help me to convert this into a dataframe in python please please.

Comment: What is in `r.json()`?

Comment: I didnt understand your question.

Comment: What is returned when you print `r.json()`? And is `r.text` one long list or does it contain multiple lists?

Comment: {'selection1': [{'name': 'Radisson Blu Azuri Resort & Spa', 'url': 'https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/radisson-blu-azuri-resort-hotel-deals.html', 'CommentID': [{'name': '137', 'Date': 'February 02, 2020', 'comment': 'I enjoy the daily package from the start with the welcoming up to the end.\nI recommend this hotel.'}, {'name': '136', 'Date': 'September 07, 2019', 'comment': 'enjoy a lovely moment'}, {'name': '135', 'Date': 'July 15, 2019', 'comment': 'I was there for my honeymoon. The hotel was simply wooww and wonderful. ALL the hotel staff was extremely friendly and made......}]}]}

Comment: the above is appeared when I print r.json().

Comment: And what is `r.text`, one long list or multiple lists within one list?

Comment: {
 "selection1": [
  {
   "name": "Radisson Blu Azuri Resort & Spa",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/radisson-blu-azuri-resort-hotel-deals.html",
   "CommentID": [
    {
     "name": "137",
     "Date": "February 02, 2020",
     "comment": "I enjoy the daily package from the start with the welcoming up to the end.\nI recommend this hotel."
    },
    {
     "name": "136","Date": "September 07, 2019",
     "comment": "enjoy a lovely moment"
    },
    {
     "name": "135",
     "Date": "July 15, 2019",
     "comment": "I was there for my honeymoon. The hotel....

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot for the r.text

Comment: Sorry sir, I have put a screenshot in the answer section.

Comment: I see, that is a screenshot of `r.json()`, could you also show a screenshot of `r.text`? It doesn't have to be in an answer, you can also just paste a link in a comment.

Comment: I am having the same for running print(r.text)

Comment: What do you get when converting it to a pandas dataframe? So using the following code:

`import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(r.text)`

Comment: I am having : ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: And what if you use: `pd.DataFrame(eval(r.text))`?

Comment: I have posted the answer in the answer section. I am sorry I am having difficulties to add the screenshot as a link.

Comment: I did pd.DataFrame(eval(r.text)). 
If I do pd.DataFrame(eval(r.json())).I get this error: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

params = {
  "api_key": "abc",
  "format": "csv"
}
r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs/ttx8PT-EL6Rf/data', params=params)
r = r.content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: I got the table but it is not complete. This is the screenshot:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ocNn.png. What should I do to have the complete dataframe?

Comment: It looks good to me, what are you missing? Looking at the example you showed in your OP all columns seem to be present.

Comment: it is showing dot dot dot... why am I not having the whole table?

Comment: They are there, if you look at the bottom of your screenshot it shows the dimensions of the dataframe, which is 1209 rows by 5 columns. The dots just indicate that there is data there but is it not printing it because there is no space to print all data.

Comment: oh.. Thank you very much Sir. I am very grateful to you.